# ClosedXML - Creating multiple pivot tables

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, export-to-excel, closedxml

I am trying to export some data to an excel sheet `S1` whose data would be shown as Pivoted views in the next two sheets `S2 and S3`. I am able to create a single pivot and it works perfect. But when I create two pivots, the consequent Excel file renders as corrupt.

By corrupt I mean, 
[image]

On clicking yes, I get this -

[image: Corrupt]

Here is the code I am using to create the pivots -

```
using XL = ClosedXML.Excel;
...
XL.XLWorkbook wb = new XL.XLWorkbook();
dsData = Session["ExportData"] as DataSet;

var sheet1 = wb.Worksheets.Add("output table");
sheet1.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dsData.Tables[0], "output table", true);

// sheet1 is the reference sheet S1
var dataRange = sheet1.RangeUsed();

// First Pivot
XL.IXLWorksheet ptSheet1 = wb.Worksheets.Add("S2");

var pt1 = ptSheet1.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable1", ptSheet.Cell(3, 1), dataRange);


pt1.ReportFilters.Add("CX");

pt1.RowLabels.Add("C1");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C2");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C3");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C4");

pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL1");
pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL2");
pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL3");

pt1.Values.Add("V").SummaryFormula = XL.XLPivotSummary.Sum;


// Second Pivot
XL.IXLWorksheet ptSheet2 = wb.Worksheets.Add("S3");

var pt2 = ptSheet2.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable2", ptSheet1.Cell(3, 1), dataRange);

pt2.ReportFilters.Add("QQ");

pt2.RowLabels.Add("C1");
pt2.RowLabels.Add("C2");

pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL1");
pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL2");
pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL3");

pt2.Values.Add("V").SummaryFormula = XL.XLPivotSummary.Sum;
```

`C1, C2, C3. C4 and V` are the column names in my reference sheet `S1`.

Comment: what do you mean by renders as corrupt? any error(s) occur? please show us the whole code for exporting

Comment: @jomsk1e I have updated the question, please check.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue . . did you ever figure out a solution or a workaround?

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/87

Comment: @leora Sorry, but we did not find a solution. We ended up building the Excel with OpenXML instead. That worked.

Comment: @leora I am no longer working on the requirement / project. I will be happy to accept an answer if anyone can confirm that any of the answers indeed work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is caused by a [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) implementation bug.

It can easily be reproduced by using the following snippet (a modified version of their Pivot Tables example) and opening the resulting file in Excel:

```
static void CreateTestPivotTables(string filePath)
{
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();

    var wsData = wb.Worksheets.Add("Data");            
    wsData.Cell("A1").Value = "Category";
    wsData.Cell("A2").Value = "A";
    wsData.Cell("A3").Value = "B";
    wsData.Cell("A4").Value = "B";
    wsData.Cell("B1").Value = "Number";
    wsData.Cell("B2").Value = 100;
    wsData.Cell("B3").Value = 150;
    wsData.Cell("B4").Value = 75;
    var source = wsData.Range("A1:B4");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        var name = "PT" + i;
        var wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add(name);
        var pt = wsPT.PivotTables.AddNew(name, wsPT.Cell("A1"), source);
        pt.RowLabels.Add("Category");
        pt.Values.Add("Number")
            .ShowAsPctFrom("Category").And("A")
            .NumberFormat.Format = "0%";
    }

    wb.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

The bug is located in [XLWorkbook_Save.cs](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook_Save.cs) - `GeneratePivotTables` method:

```
private static void GeneratePivotTables(WorkbookPart workbookPart, WorksheetPart worksheetPart,
    XLWorksheet xlWorksheet,
    SaveContext context)
{
    foreach (var pt in xlWorksheet.PivotTables)
    {
        var ptCdp = context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook);

        var pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart>(ptCdp);
        GeneratePivotTableCacheDefinitionPartContent(pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, pt);

        var pivotCaches = new PivotCaches();
        var pivotCache = new PivotCache {CacheId = 0U, Id = ptCdp};

        pivotCaches.AppendChild(pivotCache);

        workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(pivotCaches);

        var pivotTablePart =
            worksheetPart.AddNewPart<PivotTablePart>(context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook));
        GeneratePivotTablePartContent(pivotTablePart, pt);

        pivotTablePart.AddPart(pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook));
    }
}
```

by the line `workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(pivotCaches);` which adds multiple `PivotCaches` to `workbookPart.Workbook` while it's allowed to contain 0 or 1.

With that being said, the only way to fix it is inside the source code by modifying the above method as follows:

```
private static void GeneratePivotTables(WorkbookPart workbookPart, WorksheetPart worksheetPart,
    XLWorksheet xlWorksheet,
    SaveContext context)
{
    var pivotCaches = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<PivotCaches>();
    foreach (var pt in xlWorksheet.PivotTables)
    {
        var ptCdp = context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook);

        var pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<PivotTableCacheDefinitionPart>(ptCdp);
        GeneratePivotTableCacheDefinitionPartContent(pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, pt);

        if (pivotCaches == null)
            workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(pivotCaches = new PivotCaches());
        var pivotCache = new PivotCache { CacheId = (uint)pivotCaches.Count(), Id = ptCdp };
        pivotCaches.AppendChild(pivotCache);

        var pivotTablePart =
            worksheetPart.AddNewPart<PivotTablePart>(context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook));
        GeneratePivotTablePartContent(pivotTablePart, pt);
        pivotTablePart.PivotTableDefinition.CacheId = pivotCache.CacheId;

        pivotTablePart.AddPart(pivotTableCacheDefinitionPart, context.RelIdGenerator.GetNext(RelType.Workbook));
    }
}
```

**Update:** The good news are that my post triggered a [ClosedXML source repository fix](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/87) by [Francois Botha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179494/francois-botha) (also credits to [petelids](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791802/petelids) who brought it up there), so you can take the code from there until their next release which hopefully will include it.

Comment: As a maintainer of the package, I'd love it if people could submit patches as pull requests. http://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: @FrancoisBotha Sure, I've just worked yesterday on the questions and haven't time for contributing (it has some additional requirements I guess, not like just throwing a code snippet), and then the user petelids seems to already did that.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I did but I rushed it and made a bit of a hash of it. I've deleted my answer as it wasn't adding any value (and upvoted yours instead). FrancoisBotha has created a better patch.

Comment: @IvanStoev No problem. Nice to see some kind of involvement from the community in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this modification. I made a note where I added an additional line. Also, I think the `AddNew()` method may have had the wrong worksheet reference? You may have been trying to add a pivot table on top of another one. That may have been the real issue rather than the additional line I added.

```
using XL = ClosedXML.Excel;
...
XL.XLWorkbook wb = new XL.XLWorkbook();
dsData = Session["ExportData"] as DataSet;
var sheet1 = wb.Worksheets.Add("output table");
sheet1.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dsData.Tables[0], "output table", true);

// sheet1 is the reference sheet S1
var dataRange = sheet1.RangeUsed();
PivotCache cache = wb.PivotCaches.Add(dataRange); //---THIS LINE HAS BEEN ADDED---

// First Pivot
XL.IXLWorksheet ptSheet1 = wb.Worksheets.Add("S2");
var pt1 = ptSheet1.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable1", ptSheet1.Cell(3, 1), cache);  
//Changed ptSheet.Cell... to ptSheet1.Cell...
pt1.ReportFilters.Add("CX");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C1");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C2");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C3");
pt1.RowLabels.Add("C4");
pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL1");
pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL2");
pt1.ColumnLabels.Add("CL3");
pt1.Values.Add("V").SummaryFormula = XL.XLPivotSummary.Sum;

// Second Pivot
XL.IXLWorksheet ptSheet2 = wb.Worksheets.Add("S3");
var pt2 = ptSheet2.PivotTables.AddNew("PivotTable2", ptSheet2.Cell(3, 1), cache);  
//Changed ptSheet1.Cell... to ptSheet2.Cell...
pt2.ReportFilters.Add("QQ");
pt2.RowLabels.Add("C1");
pt2.RowLabels.Add("C2");
pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL1");
pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL2");
pt2.ColumnLabels.Add("CL3");
pt2.Values.Add("V").SummaryFormula = XL.XLPivotSummary.Sum;
```