# Multiple Pivot tables ClosedXML

Tags: c#, closedxml

Using latest Closed XML (0.76) on Net 4.5.1

Created a Worksheet with a table by:

```
 DataTable Table = ...

 var DataWorkSheet = Workbook.Worksheets.Any(x => x.Name == "Data") ?
   Workbook
     .Worksheets
     .First(x => x.Name == "Data") :
   Workbook
     .Worksheets
     .Add("Data");

 int Start = ... // calculate cell start

 var Source = DataWorkSheet
   .Cell(Start, 1)
   .InsertTable(Table, Name, true);

 var Range = Source.DataRange;
```

This is done inside a loop (i.e. multiple tables in the "Data" sheet).  A problem arises where the generated Excel document can't be opened if multiple pivot tables are created in a separate sheet.

```
 var PivotWorkSheet = Workbook
   .Worksheets
   .Add(Name);

 var Pivot = PivotWorkSheet
   .PivotTables
   .AddNew(Name, PivotWorkSheet.Cell(1, 1), DataRange);
```

Any ideas why and how to debug?

Comment: Fixed in http://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/87

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the same issue as in [ClosedXML - Creating multiple pivot tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432347/closedxml-creating-multiple-pivot-tables/40346021#40346021).

For the record, it's caused by `ClosedXML` bug which requires source code modification as in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432347/closedxml-creating-multiple-pivot-tables/40346021#40346021) of the linked question.